# SQL Anywhere Error - 141: Table 'syslanguages' not found

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

I tried to login into a sybase db with valid credentials using Ase isql application. But, I'm keep getting the SQL Anywhere Error - 141: Table 'syslanguages' not found.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains the answer: ASE and SQL Anywhere are two entirely different databases, though both happen to come from the company named Sybase (now SAP).
The 'syslanguages' table is specific for ASE, but given the error message, you are connected to a SQL Anywhere server (or Sybase IQ, which contains SQL Anywhere).
SQL Anywhere manages localized languages in a different way than ASE and hence there is no 'syslanguages' table. To get more details, search the SQL ANywhere documentation for 'dblang', 'SALANG' and 'localization'.